# Salesforce Login Issue through Web Service

Tags: integration

Need suggestion on the below issue.
When I am trying to connect Salesforce.com through Web Service API by using username,(Password+Security Token) and End-point URL getting the below error. But using the same credentials able to login through browser as well as through data loader.

> Error: sf:INVALID_LOGININVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or
>   user locked out.  INVALID_LOGINInvalid username,
>   password, security token; or user locked out.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same login url? Maybe mixing up test.salesforce.com & login.salesforce.com?

Comment: yes, I am using this one: https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/39.0/ODF14000000POQm

Comment: Please check downgrading the SOAP API . What does login history say ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when you sure the credentials are correct, you should try to login with the custom domain URL like: https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com, also it depends what instance you want to login check production / sandbox environments urls.

Comment: Thanks Yucel. The issue has been resolved after using Salesforce Instance URl (my domain URL )